# Compute the following sum

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation

I am to compute the following sum and my professor wrote this on the board. Although I can see what he is doing here and how to use the S and 2S I can't figure out the steps that are highlighted in yellow. Like, where did the (n-2)2^(n-1) come from? Also, how is it that 2(n-1)2^(n-1) is equivalent to (n-1)2^n?

[image]

Comment: $2*2^k = 2^{k+1}$. Your professor is simply absorbing each $2$ into the $2^j$ terms.

Comment: could you expand? Where is this happening?

Comment: Notice that, in the second line for $2S$ you have $2*2=2^2$, $4*2^2 = 2*2^3$, and so on marked.  Continuing this, for each i you have $2*i*2^i = i*2^{i+1}$ and hence you get $2*n*2^n = n*2^{n+1}$.

Comment: I'm confused as to where the n-1 and n-2 came from in the picture? And in your answer, you get S-2S = $n*2^(n+1)$ from 2S = $2*n*2^n$? Are the other steps not needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask: `Also, how is it that 2(n-1)2^(n-1) is equivalent to (n-1)2^n?`

this is just $2\cdot (n-1)\cdot 2^{n-1}$

Because multiplication is commutative, you can change the order to

$(n-1)\cdot 2\cdot 2^{n-1}$

Then combine the 2's giving you

$(n-1)\cdot 2^{n}$

`where did the (n-2)2^(n-1) come from?`

In that line where he's simplifying 2S, he's multiplying the 2 into the power of 2 in each term.  so Instead of thinking of $6\cdot 2^3$ he's thinking $2\cdot 3\cdot 2^3$ then using the same trick as above, moving the 2 over and incorporating it into the power of 2, so that's $3\cdot 2\cdot 2^3$ which is equal to $3\cdot 2^4$ -- following that pattern you end up with the general term looking like $n\cdot 2^{n+1}$ and the terms below that which start with $(n-2)$ and $(n-1)$ just follow that pattern with $n-2$ or $n-1$ subbed in for n in the general term.

hope that makes sense